# How do you call a method in your view, that is located in your viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

Basically, I have a rectangle, and I want the Photos Library to open when the user touches the rectangle.

I tried instantiating the viewcontroller as an object in my view class, but was not very successful as my `openPhotoLibrary()` never runs.

Code that may be helpful.

**Edited**
I tried delegates, but am still struggling.

View Class

```
protocol PhotoLibraryDelegate {
    func openPhotoLibrary(sender: ImagePipView)
}

class ImagePipView: BasePipView{
    var delegate: PhotoLibraryDelegate?
    var addPhotoFrame = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(frame.width/2 - 30, 60, 60, 60))
    addPhotoFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    addPhotoFrame.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addPhotoTouched:"))
    addSubview(addPhotoFrame)

    func addPhotoTouched(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        println("PHOTO TOUCHED")
        delegate?.openPhotoLibrary(self)

}
```

ViewController class

```
class CameraViewControllerTest: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, PhotoLibraryDelegate{

  init() {
    super.init(nibName:"MyNib", bundle:nil)
    var productRequest: ImagePipView?
    productRequest?.delegate = self
  }

  func openPhotoLibrary(){
    println ("inside photo library")
    var photoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    photoPicker.delegate = self
    photoPicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a delegate between your controller and your UIView, in the same manner than the UITableViewDelegate. Create a delegate instance in your view, and from your controller, when instantiating your view, set `myView.delegate = self`. You just have to implement the protocol in your controller then.

You can find a tutorial on delegation in Swift [here](http://nscurious.com/2014/06/04/create-protocol-and-implement-delegation-in-swift/).

Comment: Thanks! I just added a delegate but am still running into the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` issue. Do you have any idea why?

The error occurs when I call `delegate.openPhotoLibrary()`

Comment: Are you sure you assigned your delegate before calling this instruction? Try `delegate?.openPhotoLibrary() instead`, which prevents crash in case your delegate is `nil`.

Comment: Awesome. The "?" helped because now I don't get an error, but I notice it's not calling the function properly.. because it doesn't even print the first line in the function `println ("inside photo library")`. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, the "?" prevents a crash if you try to access a property of a `nil` object. However you must understand why your delegate is `nil`. When you instantiate your `ImagePipView` instance, assign the delegate to your parent controller!

Comment: I also tried that!

`class CameraViewControllerTest: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, PhotoLibraryDelegate{
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName:"MyNib", bundle:nil)
        var productRequest: ImagePipView?
        productRequest?.delegate = self
    }` but alas, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access controller in view. Instead in your controller add the tap gesture to your view, thus your controller has a reference to your ImagePipView instance.